# MySQL tricky multiple row insert/update into two tables

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update, multiple-tables, multiple-records

There are two tables with the following columns:

```
table1 (id1, id2)  //pairs (id1, id2) - are unique 
table2 (id2, name) //id2 - is auto incrementing, name - string
```

from PHP i have 100-300 pairs (id1, name) which have to be inserted into tables with the following conditions:

1. some (id1, id2) pairs can be not yet in table1, but 'name' could be already in table2. In this case only table1 has to be filled with corresponding id1, id2.
2. if (id1, id2) pair is already in table1 - then 'name' in table2 has to be updated, if its not the same.

How to accomplish it with performance in mind?

PS: i can not  use foreign keys or fuse tables

> EDIT: here is an example, just to demonstrate the logic

Given 100-300 pairs of (id1,name):

```
id1   |  name
--------------
 5    |  name0
10    |  name1
20    |  name2
30    |  XXXXX
```

Tables table1 and table2 are either empty or contain some records:

```
table1:                 table2:
id1   |  id2            id2   |  name
--------------          ----------------
 5    |  0              0     |  name0
      |                 1     |  name1
30    |  2              2     |  YYYYY
```

After insertion of the given pairs tables should contain:

```
table1:                 table2:
id1   |  id2            id2   |  name
--------------          ----------------
 5    |  0              0     |  name0      <-not touched
10    |  1              1     |  name1      <-table1 updated
30    |  2              2     |  XXXXX      <-changed name
20    |  3              3     |  name2      <-inserted into both tables
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate this logic on sample data?

Comment: Can you demonstrate what you've tried? SO is about exactly this.

Comment: To make your third example (changing name) work, `id1` in table 1 must be unique. If that is the case, your tables are over-normalized, and `name` should replace `id2`, so table 2 can be dropped.